# JSDOM's querySelectorAll returned too many XML elements

Tags: node.js, jsdom

Node.js version: 10.15.3
jsdom version: 15.1.0

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const xmlFile = fs.readFileSync("question.xml", "utf8");
const dom = new JSDOM(xmlFile);
const all = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("S");
console.log(all);
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Foo>
        <FooBar>
            <S a="string1" b="string2" c="string3"/>
        </FooBar>
    </Foo>
    <Foo>
        <FooBar>
            <S a="string1" b="string2"/>
            <S a="string1"/>
        </FooBar>
    </Foo>
```

`querySelectorAll("S")` returns 7 HTML elements when there are clearly only 3. What makes it even stranger is if I rename the xml elements from `S` to `F`, it works correctly and `querySelectorAll("F")` finds only 3 elements. What is the cause of this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, JSDOM interprets the markup you give to it as HTML. So it interprets your XML as HTML, and you get funky results. Remember that the HTML specification provides rules about how to make sense of broken HTML so when JSDOM reads your XML, it applies the rules and tries to get some sensible document out of it. If I take your XML and your code but I add

```
console.log(dom.window.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

just after the line that assigns `dom`, I get this serialized HTML:

```
<head></head><body><foo>
        <foobar>
            <s a="string1" b="string2" c="string3">
        </s></foobar><s a="string1" b="string2" c="string3">
    </s></foo><s a="string1" b="string2" c="string3">
    <foo>
        <foobar>
            <s a="string1" b="string2">
            <s a="string1">
        </s></s></foobar><s a="string1" b="string2"><s a="string1">
    </s></s></foo><s a="string1" b="string2"><s a="string1">
</s></s></s></body>
```

Look at what happens to `s`. (Reminder: HTML element names are case-insensitive so `S` and `s` are the same HTML element.)

By the way, the reason you get different behavior with `S` by opposition to `F` is because `S` is an [actual HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s), whereas `F` is not. So JSDOM applies different rules to `S` than `F` when it tries to make sense of your document as HTML.

In order for JSDOM to interpret your document as XML, you can do this:

```
const dom = new JSDOM(xmlFile, { contentType: "text/xml" });
```

But note that your document is not well-formed XML because it has more than one root element. The XML specification does not provide any rule for making sense of documents that are not well-formed. A document which is not well-formed is essentially not XML. So JSDOM will just reject your document. You need to edit it so that it has only one root element. For instance, this would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
   <Foo>
        <FooBar>
            <S a="string1" b="string2" c="string3"/>
        </FooBar>
    </Foo>
    <Foo>
        <FooBar>
            <S a="string1" b="string2"/>
            <S a="string1"/>
        </FooBar>
    </Foo>
</doc>
```

I've just wrapped the two `Foo` elements in a `doc` element which forms the single root required by XML.

Comment: Thank you! I can keep using jsdom then, I was worried I'll need to find another one that supports JS selectors. Turns out that `{ contentType: "text/xml" }` was the only thing missing as my example for this question was heavily edited and I managed to remove the wrapping element by mistake. Now it works perfectly. Do you know of any other xml parser that would be faster than JSDOM and would support JS-like selectors?

Comment: You mean CSS-like selectors, right? There's [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) but I never used it. And whether it would work depends on your specific needs. If you need to model the DOM *in addition* to CSS selectors, then Cheerio won't work. Also, if you need to reject malformed documents, I don't think Cheerio would work. It uses `htmlparser2`, which is advertised as a *forgiving* HTML/XML/RSS parser but the XML spec does not define any forgiving parsing of XML. (Contrarily to the HTML spec, as I mentioned above.) And I don't know whether it is in fact faster than JSDOM.

Comment: Indeed @Louis, I meant CSS selector. I am staying with jsdom for now.